Doubt in derivation for distance between two points in three dimensions
In my book, a derivation of the distance between any two points in three dimensions has been given. And there's this diagram along with it:

How is ∠PAQ = 90°? I can't make heads or tails of it. They've provided no explanation in the text of the derivation, simply saying that:

...since ∠PAQ is a right
angle, it follows that, in triangle PAQ,
PQ² = PA² + AQ²

PS: for reference, the text can be found at the 4th page of the linked PDF

$PA$ is perpendicular to plane $QAN$.

Intuitive hint: $QAN$ is like the vertical tail fin of an airplane. $PAQ$, despite its appearance when rendered flat in this image, is a (right) triangle with acute points at $P$ and $Q$, shaped like the wing of an airplane banking away from you (fuselage $PA$), with a right angle at $A$.

Plane QNA and the side of the rectangular prism it contains are perpendicular to the plane containing the face at the back of the prism (and thus are also perpendicular to that face).  Since the two planes are perpendicular, $\overline{PA}$ is perpendicular to any line (or line segment that extends far enough to intersect $\overline{PA}$) in Plane QNA (just like a flagpole coming straight out of the ground is perpendicular to every line or line segment along the ground that intersects the bottom of the flagpole).
